# Anaconda show error under cursor on current line

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

I would like to know if it is possible in Anaconda to show more information about the error on the current line. I have only found `context menu > Anaconda > Show error list`, but this shows all the errors and I just want some information about the error on the current line. Is there a command in Anaconda that does that?